# How to restrict NDepend methods query on type attribute

Tags: c#, ndepend, cql, cqlinq

I'm trying to get NDepend to identify long methods using a modified version of the standard "Methods too big" query.

I don't want to report long methods that the developers have little control over, so I filter out generated code using the `DebuggerNonUserCode` attribute and `InitializeComponent()`.

Unfortunately, I still get a few false positives as methods in generated types are reported as well. The problem is that while the type itself has the `DebuggerNonUserCode` attribute, the methods do not, so they are included in the output despite the fact that they are generated.

I am looking for something like a join between types and methods: Give me all types that do not have the `DebuggerNonUserCode` attribute and run the query on those, but I can't figure out how to express this in CQL.

For some of the assemblies, I can simply filter on the full name, but unfortunately some of our assemblies mix developer made and generated types. Unfortunately the `IsGeneratedByCompiler` can't be used either in this case.

My query

```
WARN IF Count > 0 IN SELECT METHODS WHERE 
   NbLinesOfCode > 30 AND
   !HasAttribute "System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute" AND
   !NameIs "InitializeComponent()"
   ORDER BY NbLinesOfCode DESC
```

Comment: I could not find either a way to join methods and type info and even the release notes of V3 don't mention this.

Comment: Have you tried the IsGeneratedByCompiler method attribute ?

Comment: @Timores: Exactly, I wish I could make a join between the two. 

I haven't looked at IsGeneratedByCompiler. From the documentation it doesn't seem to do the trick. but I'll give it a shot anyway and update the question.

Comment: I have sent a request to NDepend's support. I'll update the comment or post an answer when I get something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brian, thanks to [Code Rule over LINQ Query (CQLinq)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) the source code of the code rule you are asking for is:

```
warnif count > 0
from m in Application.Methods where
  m.NbLinesOfCode > 30 &&
 !m.ParentType.HasAttribute( "System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute") &&
  m.Name != "InitializeComponent()"
orderby m.NbLinesOfCode descending
select new { m, m.NbLinesOfCode }
```

The CQLinq syntax also offer a way to define what is *Just-My-Code*. This feature is describe [here](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CQLinq_Syntax.aspx#NotMyCode). Basically you need to define the set **JustMyCode** through queries prefixed with **notmycode**. Then the rule you are asking for can be rewritten easily:

```
warnif count > 0
from m in JustMyCode.Methods where
   m.NbLinesOfCode > 30
orderby m.NbLinesOfCode descending    
select new { m, m.NbLinesOfCode }
```

The set **JustMyCode** defined once for all can be reused over any code rule. Additionaly you can look at the **notmycode** default query [Discard generated and designer Methods from JustMyCode](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Discard_generated_and_designer_Methods_from_JustMyCode.html)

Answer (score 0):

I quite like NDepend, but it's still the biggest single shortcoming that namespace/type/method info cannot be joined into a single query. That feature would make CQL really powerful stuff.

Apart from that the checks '*IsGeneratedByCompiler*' and '*IsInFrameworkAssembly*' may be helpful. 
You can also remover certain namespaces from the query (*OUT OF NAMESPACES "..."*)

Comment: It certainly would! I'm aware of the OUT OF feature, but unfortunately the relevant assemblies lump both dev made code and generate code in the same namespace :(

Comment: flq, Brian, look at my answer above :)